# Change/update single line in HERE Data Lens dataset

Tags: here-api

I'd like to update/change a single line in a HERE Data Lens dataset. I've been looking for an answer in the Data Lens Developer's Guide but could neither find a relevant API nor a way to change my data with a query.

Do you know of any way to change one line of data without deleting and re-creating the whole set? Is this possible at all?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, updating your ingested dataset is not possible at the moment. You will need to update the dataset and upload it anew. You can use our Data Manager @ https://datalens.here.com for easily uploading, deleting and managing your datasets.

-Sherzod | PM for HERE Geovisualization/DataLens